# Using partial view inside a Html.BeginForm sends null model to controller action method

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

**My Get ActionMethod :**

```
        public ActionResult GetData(int id)
        {
            TestModel testModel = new DataAccess().GetData(id);
            return View(testModel);
        }

View 


@model TestModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateRequest", "Home", FormMethod.Post))

{

    <div>
        @Html.Partial("_Information", Model.Information)
    </div>

    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Save" />
}
```

The data is displayed correctly in the _Information partial view. But when I click on Save button the model passed to Controller is null.

**Home Controller method is as follows :**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateRequest(TestModel testModel)
    {
        new DataAccess().UpdateData(testModel);
        .....
    }
```

But the model received for UpdateRequest is null
Please help to resolve this issue.

**Note**: The partial view does not contain any additional BeginForm Tags.
If the individual controls of the Partial view are added in the main View the model object is populated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked what the form collection has in it when the controller posts back?
I would hazard a guess that the HtmlFieldPrefix is being set which is causing your form controls to have a strange name that doesn't match your POCO.

You can chance the HtmlFieldPrefix in your partial view to match the sub object that you want to set by using:

```
@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "Your sub object property name here"
```

HTH

Comment: I am having a very similar problem as the OP. I have read your answer, but I do not understand what you are talking about. Could you elaborate?

Comment: This is a very old question now and was for MVC5.  Probably better off asking a new question for the version of MVC you are using

Comment: I am using MVC5. When I posted a question, it was closed as a duplicate of this one. SO is stupid sometimes.

Comment: Well, back in the day when I used this, I remember when you had a nested partial, i.e. a view that called Html.EditorFor(m => m.MySubObject), it would add a prefix to the form collection, something like MySubObject.PropertyName.  If your action didn't take in the parent object and just expected MySubObject, it would get all nulls.  The way around it was to set the HtmlFieldPrefix to an empty string, so rather than MySubObject.PropertyName in the form collection, you got just PropertyName and the model binding worked correctly